# React Hook "useContext" is called in function "age" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useContext react hook.

**Age.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react' ;
import Detail from '../context/detail';

const age = props =>{
    const detail = useContext(Detail);
    return(
        <p>
            Your age is : {detail.age}
        </p>
    );
}

export default age ;
```

It gives an **error** like this :
`React Hook "useContext" is called in function "age" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Function components should start with uppercase , rename age  to Age, to get rid of the error