# React Hook use Context error in react.js with hooks

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I am trying to import my context into the component it's giving error "React hook useContext" in function incomeExpenses is neither a react function component nor custom hook.I am beginner with react help will be appreciated.

here is my app.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Balance from './components/balance'
import IncomeExpenses from './components/incomeExpenses'
import TransactionList from './components/TransactionList'
import AddExpense from './components/AddExpenses'
import {ExpenseProvider} from './components/ExpensesContext'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <ExpenseProvider>
      <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Balance/>
            <IncomeExpenses />
            <TransactionList />
            <AddExpense />
      </div>
    </ExpenseProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the component in which I am trying to import context

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import{ExpenseContext} from './ExpensesContext'
 const incomeExpenses = () => {
     const[trans,setTrans] = useContext(ExpenseContext)
     const myStyle={
         display:'flex',
         justifyContent:'space-around'
     }
    return (
        <div className="Container" style={myStyle}>
            <div>
                <h4>Income</h4>
                <p>0.00</p>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Expense</h4>
                <p id="lossMoney">0.00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default incomeExpenses;
```

here is the context component

```
import React,{createContext,useState} from 'react'

export const ExpenseContext = createContext();
export const ExpenseProvider = (props) => {
    const[trans,setTrans] = useState([
        { id: 1, text: 'Flower', amount: -20 },
        { id: 2, text: 'Salary', amount: 300 },
        { id: 3, text: 'Book', amount: -10 },
        { id: 4, text: 'Camera', amount: 150 }
    ])

    return (
        <div>
                <ExpenseContext.Provider value={[trans,setTrans]}>
                    {props.children}
                </ExpenseContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041349/react-hook-usecontext-is-called-in-function-age-which-is-neither-a-react-fun. Rename `incomeExpenses` to `IncomeExpenses `

Answer (score 0):

Use a capital letter for functional components as mentioned in the answer linked by Arpitha:

```js
const IncomeExpenses = () => {
```